# Error on android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using windows 7 32bit computer. try to update my android studio when update restart button pressed some file is download but finally not update my android studio.following window is open what is this. how to update my android studio tel me[image]

Comment: Try to [download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle) it again...

Comment: @Skizo k what is this

Comment: k what is this @Skizo

Comment: Just uninstall and reinstall, it is Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to location **C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio** here you can see the sdk folder cut that and move it one step back **C:\Program Files\Android** and . change the path of sdk from

File -> project Structure into Project Structure

Left -> SDK Location

SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)

and try again. It should work.

Comment: Which version of Android studio you are using currently

Comment: ya again same problem occurred

Comment: And you opened android Studio with admin permission(Run As administrator)

Comment: You should see this [Thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78129) also if you are using anti-virus try to turn that on and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73398/discussion-between-jack-and-ashutiwari4).